# How to link to open-source contributions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

On my http://careers.stackoverflow.com profile, there is a place to add Open Source projects.

I don't actually own any open source projects, but I contribute to a number. The value of this information on a profile shows the ability to work within an existing code base as well as other developers.

How can I add my contributions (for example, my accepted pull requests in Github)?

It seems like my Github account is linked, or can be linked but I only see "Add" on owned projects.

Or is there an accepted workaround? Could our contributions be pulled after linking our Github account?

Comment: Does think kind of thing genuinely matter to employers, especially those just looking for candidates to interview?  I would be really surprised if I failed to get an interview because I didn't include Github pull requests in my profile.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've been asked for my "portfolio" which means code you have made in the past, and since Github pull requests have code diff... that typically works.

Comment: I just received a mail from SO Careers: "We noticed that you have not edited your profile in a while. Have you changed jobs, read any good books, written any blog posts or **contributed to any open source projects lately?**". Even a "OSS contributions" section would do.